# Azure key vault - Authorization header

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-keyvault, alteryx

I'm trying to use the API below to get access to a key vault.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvault/vaults/get
When I try to run this API in Alteryx, it asks for a authorization header.
I'm not sure what information I need to provide in this authorization header in order to get access to the specific key vault.
Can someone please share some knowledge on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX90v.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like what type of API it is , where you want to connect and what you want to achieve

Comment: @Coderun Only now I realised I posted the wrong link to the API documentation in microsoft website. This is an API used to get information from a Azure Key Vault. My question is what is the authorization header I should be using to get a successful run on this API.

Comment: is it a private endpoint?

Comment: yes, it is @Coderun

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Key Vault describes its request authentication in the [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/authentication-requests-and-responses#authentication) section of this [Authentication, requests and responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/authentication-requests-and-responses) documentation:

> Access tokens must be sent to the service using the HTTP Authorization header:
>
> ```
> PUT /keys/MYKEY?api-version=<api_version>  HTTP/1.1  
> Authorization: Bearer <access_token>
> ```

The access token is a token string that can be obtained via OAuth2 authentication. An easy way to obtain access tokens for Azure resources in Python is with the [azure-identity](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/identity/azure-identity) library, which can be used with the [azure-mgmt-keyvault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-mgmt-keyvault) library to make the request you're describing here.

If you'd like to use plain REST requests instead, access tokens are described thoroughly in this [Microsoft identity platform access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) documentation.

*Disclaimer: I work with the Azure SDK for Python.*